# How to save all web page including .css .js?

Tags: android, android-webview, jsoup, androidhttpclient

I wanna save all web page including .css .js on android by programmatically.
So far I tried `html get` method and `jsoup , webview content` but all of them I could not save all page with css and js. These methods just save html parts of WEB Page. When I save the all page ,I want to open it offline.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did any of the answers below help? If yes please accept one so the thread can be considered closed. If not please provide some feedback so you can receive assistance. If you've already found another solution to your problem don't hesitate to post that and select it as the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You have to take the html, parse it and get the urls of the resources and then make requests for those urls too.

```
public class Stack {

    private static final String USER_AGENT = "";
    private static final String INITIAL_URL = "";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Document doc = Jsoup
                        .connect(INITIAL_URL)
                        .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                        .get();

        Elements scripts = doc.getElementsByTag("script");
        Elements css     = doc.getElementsByTag("link");

        for(Element s : scripts) {
            String url = s.absUrl("src");
            if(!url.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println(url);
                Document docScript = Jsoup
                                        .connect(url)
                                        .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                                        .ignoreContentType(true)
                                        .get();

                System.out.println(docScript);
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
            }
        }

        for(Element c : css) {
            String url = c.absUrl("href");
            String rel = c.attr("rel") == null ? "" : c.attr("rel");
            if(!url.isEmpty() && rel.equals("stylesheet")) {
                System.out.println(url);
                Document docScript = Jsoup
                                        .connect(url)
                                        .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                                        .ignoreContentType(true)
                                        .get();
                System.out.println(docScript);
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem...
Using this code we can get images,.css,.js. However some html contents are still missing.
For instance when we save a web page via chrome,there are 2 options.

1. Complete html
2. html only

Out of .css,.js,.php..."Complete html" consists of more elements than "only html". The requirement is to download the html as complete like chrome does in the first option.

Comment: so how can I do that in android ?

Comment: You can use this : view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                                 "('<html>'+document.documentElement.innerHTML+'</html>');");

Comment: You can use this : view.loadUrl("javascript:window.HtmlViewer.showHTML" +
                                 "('<html>'+document.documentElement.innerHTML+'</html>');");  And in your javascript class add this;  public void showHTML(String html) {
              //yourcodes here
             } The answer above navigates to all links but here the problem is getting the iframes data. Though i couldnt find a way to identify the iframe rendering has finished but if you put a delay to your code for 5 seconds you will get the whole html using the javascript above...